# Go to a public Community Home page from base URL

Tags: community, security, guest-user

The goals is to have a public home page of a community.
That the users do not have to login to see.
And when users hits the base URL of the community it is redirected to that public home page.

https://fullSB.cs189.force.com/community -> https://fullSB.cs189.force.com/community/s (No login required )

The issue is that when a user hits the main URL of the community without the "/s" which is the default directory of the home page it is still redirected to login instead of being redirected to the public home page.

If the user huts the URL with the "/s" all works fine the thing is that users will hut the base URL and not the one with the "/s".

The whole community is set to public.[image]
The home page is also set to public. [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those SF things that are a bit strange.

If you go to "Sites" from the setup nothing is seen.

[image]

The right place to add those redirects to your site is from the Community/Experience administration -> Pages -> Go to Force.com -> URL redirects
[image]

[image]

[image]